# c++ drop administrator privileges

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

My program use a library which create a data file, there is a problem that some users take a mistake to "run as administrator" my program, the result is some data file is created with Administrator owner, and normal user cannot edit it later. I am finding a way 'drop' administrator privileges, that allow my program continue run such as without user 'run as administrator'? How can I do this?

Comment: May you need fix problem with files rights?

Comment: yes, but the file is create via 3rd library so I cannot specify security attribute for file creation. I'm looking a way to change default file rights, maybe drop administrator privileges would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up with this to make owner of new object to current user.

```
if(GetTokenInformation(hToken,TokenUser,tu,buff.size(),&rw)){    
    if(!SetTokenInformation(hToken,TokenOwner,tu,buff.size())){    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Good solution, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you are asking, you need to detect if you are running as administrator, and if so, create a restricted token, and restart the program using that token.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446583(VS.85).aspx

Other ways to achive a similar result are as follows.

The owner of a file is set by default to the administrators group, for members of that group. This setting can be controlled by the local security policy:

- https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/634.mspx?mfr=true

See more here:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961992.aspx

Or, when using `CreateFile`, You can specify the owner when you create the file, using the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`, and make it either the user, or any of his groups.

Comment: Be careful to test on a machine without UAC where there is no restricted token for admin users

Comment: Another alternative is to wait for the third party library to create the file, then use [`SetFileSecurity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379577.aspx) to change its security info as needed.